# Recommended UI for tabular data where dataset has varying properties

Tags: design, data-tables

I have some data in the following format:

```
[{
        "Message": "TICKETING DUE",
        "Vendor": "SA",
        "WarningDateTime": "2024-02-09T05:30:07.867+00:00",
        "ClearedDateTime": null,
        "ClearedByConsultantID": null,
        "PropertiesList": [
          {
            "Name": "TicketingDueDate",
            "Value": "2024-02-12T00:00:00"
          },
          {
            "Name": "TicketingDueTime",
            "Value": "20:00"
          }
        ]
      }]
```

Note the PropertiesList

This contains different properties depending on Message value.

So, I will have 10 or so of these objects which I need to render. Due to the variation in properties a table seems inappropriate. At the moment it is unclear to me how much variation there is!

I would like my user to be able to read all the messages and filter by type etc

I want them to be able to read through these since they may need to perform an action as a result.

What type of UI would you guys recommend for this?

Answer (score 0):

> At the moment it is unclear to me how much variation there is!

Then you should do some research before settling on a design. Basically, you
will need this information anyway when you implement whatever design you decided on (except if you do something generic like the JSON stuff you already posted :-).

> I would like my user to be able to read all the messages and filter by type etc

The design of the filter will also depend on the kind and structure of the messages (e.g., 3 message types can be shown in another filter compared to, say, 20).

> I want them to be able to read through these since they may need to perform an action as a result.

Will that be one action per message? Multiple actions per message? One action per message group? Are messages removed (only?) after an action? Again, answers make one design more useful than other designs.

Is it clear who your users are? I.e., when they look at the list, whether they try to clear the list, how many messages they are confronted with, ...?

After all these questions, one constructive remark: Given the generality of the available information, I'd recommend what I know as a "List": A sequence of rows (without columns across all rows, basically rectangles maybe even of varying height), one for each message, where each type of message has a specific layout suited to show the data of this message type. All the layouts need to be harmonious, of course - that's why you need the list of all different message types before designing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the message is important and the properties are secondary. If this is true and there aren't any critical properties that need to be displayed upfront and be visible at all times, then you can punt all the properties that are present or may appear in the future in an expandable row as seen in the screenshots below ([source1](https://www.patternfly.org/2022.05/components/table/design-guidelines/#expandable-table) and [source2](https://uxdesign.cc/data-table-for-enterprise-ux-cb48fb9fdf1e)).

[image: Example 1 with expandable row]

[image]